# Prove that the following limit depending on $\alpha$ is $0$

Tags: limits, derivatives

Let $f$ be a smooth function with $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=+\infty$, $\lim_{x\to \infty}f'(x)=+\infty$ for $x\in [x_0,+\infty)$, $x_0>0$. I want to show that
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x f'(x)}{(x^2+f(x)^2)^\alpha}=0,
$$
for $\alpha>c>0$, which I should determine.

I guess that I only need $\alpha>1$ to have the result. I am trying to prove it using Taylor expansion but I am not getting a clear argument. Is there any other way to do it or a clever use of Taylor series?